# Get values of a column having more than a certain value for given number of times

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe `df`as:

```
  Election Year     Votes   Votes %     Party              Region   
0   2000            42289   29.40   Janata Dal (United)     A
1   2000            27618   19.20   Rashtriya Janata Dal    B
2   2000            20886   14.50   Bahujan Samaj Party     C 
3   2000            17747   12.40   Congress                D
4   2000            14047   9.80    Independent             E
5   2005            8358    5.80    Janvadi Party           A
6   2005            4428    13.10   Independent             B
7   2005            1647    1.20    Independent             C
8   2005            1610    11.10   Independent             D
9   2005            1334    15.06   Nationalist  Party      E
10  2010            1114    0.80    Independent             A
11  2010            1042    10.5    Bharatiya Janta Dal     B
12  2010            835     0.60    Independent             C
13  2010            14305   15.50   Independent             D
14  2010            22211   17.70   Congress                E
```

I need to find The "Regions" in which 3 parties or more got greater than 10% of the vote shares in each "Election Year".

I have sorted the Election year in ascending year and Votes% in descending by:

```
 df1 = df.sort_values(['Election Year','Votes %'], ascending = (True, False))
```

Then I have taken top 3 of each region:

```
top_3 = df1.groupby(['Election Year', 'Region']).head(3).reset_index()
```

Now how to check if the top 3 Regions have 10% or more votes in each year?

Comment: what does your expected output df look like?

Comment: I just need the list of regions in which 3 or more parties get more than 10% vote % in each election year.

Comment: so in your example df, no region would be returned?

Comment: This is just a representation. There might be no region in this case. I apologize for that. But if there is any such region, which is actually in my dataset, how to proceed to get that output?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
def election(df):
    count = df['Votes %'].gt(10).sum()
    regions = ','.join(df['Region'].where(df['Votes %'].gt(10),'None').tolist())
    return pd.Series({'count':count,'regions':regions})
ndf = df.groupby(['Election Year','Party']).apply(election)
ndf = ndf.replace(['None,','None'],'',regex=True)
```

or

```
df.loc[df['Votes %'].gt(10).groupby(df['Election Year']).transform('sum').gt(3) & df['Votes %'].gt(10)].groupby('Election Year')['Region'].agg(','.join)
```