# Getting sub-dataframe based on difference of top two values of a column in grouped dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have a dataframe `df`as:

```
  Election Year     Votes   Vote %      Party              Region   
0   2000            42289   29.40   Janata Dal (United)     A
1   2000            27618   19.20   Rashtriya Janata Dal    A
2   2000            20886   14.50   Bahujan Samaj Party     B 
3   2000            17747   12.40   Congress                B
4   2000            14047   19.80   Independent             C
5   2000            17047   10.80   JLS                     C
6   2005            8358    15.80   Janvadi Party           A
7   2005            4428    13.10   Independent             A
8   2005            1647    1.20    Independent             B
9   2005            1610    11.10   Independent             B
10  2005            1334    15.06   Nationalist             C
11  2005            1834    18.06   NJM                     C
12  2010            21114   20.80   Independent             A
13  2010            1042    10.5    Bharatiya Janta Dal     A
14  2010            835     0.60    Independent             B
15  2010            14305   15.50   Independent             B
16  2010            22211   17.70   Congress                C
16  2010            20011   14.70   INC                     C
```

How can I get the dataframe containing regions with top two parties having difference in "Vote %" is less than 10?

Desired output:

```
Election Year    Region    Vote %
  2000             B        14.50
  2000             B        12.40
  2000             C        19.80
  2000             C        10.80
  2005             A        15.80
  2005             A        13.10
  2005             B        1.20
  2005             B        11.10
  2005             C        15.06
  2005             C        18.06
  2010             C        17.70
  2010             C        14.70
```

I tried by doing the grouping by "Election Year", and "Region". And then sorting based on "Vote %". But I am unable to figure out how to get all the regions having vote % difference less than 10.

Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: This seems to be going in the [xy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) direction. What problem are you actually trying to solve that none of these questions over two accounts did: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67920049/15497888,  https://stackoverflow.com/q/67912772/15497888, https://stackoverflow.com/q/67912460/15497888

Comment: I have to solve a few questions. Actually I am new to python and pandas. Therefore questions I am asking might sounds very easry for you but not for me. And I am really sorry for that. Please don'ttake it otherwise. And all these questions are based on same dataframe. I could solve a few only.  And I really need help to solve others as I do not have much time left.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df[df.groupby(['Election Year', 'Region'])['Vote %'].diff().abs().bfill() < 10]

    Election Year  Votes  Vote %                          Party Region
2            2000  20886   14.50            Bahujan Samaj Party      B
3            2000  17747   12.40                       Congress      B
4            2000  14047   19.80                    Independent      C
5            2000  17047   10.80                            JLS      C
6            2005   8358   15.80             JanvadiParty Party      A
7            2005   4428   13.10                    Independent      A
8            2005   1647    1.20                    Independent      B
9            2005   1610   11.10                    Independent      B
10           2005   1334   15.06                    Nationalist      C
11           2005   1834   18.06                            NJM      C
16           2010  22211   17.70                       Congress      C
17           2010  20011   14.70                            INC      C
```

Since you already have only the 2 biggest parties, you can use the above code. First groupby year and region, then get the difference in percentage votes. Then use the absolute value of difference to prevent negative numbers, then backfill all entries, so each row has a value. Then compare with 10.

Comment: Thank you for your kind reply. How to approach if the dataframe has more number of parties for a single region and more of them getting 10% or more votes?

Comment: @Andreas, could you please explain on the `.bfill()` part. I am new to pandas and first time I am encoutering it.

Comment: @KarthikS Ofc, the `.bfill` means backfill. The groupby returns the difference per group, but in the initial format. This means each group essentially has 2 rows. But the first row does not have a difference, because it is only 1 value, therefore the difference value for the first row is `nan`. `.bfill` is now used to back-fill existing values in the previous empty rows. The opposit would be `.ffill` which fills downwards. Hope it makes sense, otherwise just have a look at the pandas docu.

Comment: @Dpknew You would need to create a new question for this. But basically it should still work, returning 3 parties for example instead of 2

Comment: @Andreas, I need to get the difference of top two parties only. For this, will it be the same as I think we might need to sort the "Vote %" in descending order for each region every year? Do I need to update the question as crearing new question is getting reported. It is taking time as I am new to Python and Pandas etc.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use `DataFrame.groupby` on the year and region columns, then call `agg` on the result with a custom function that sorts the vote percentages and calculates the difference between the two largest values